# defining which user untar and make the programs for files

Tags: users

I have untar and compiled the source files for the software. How I know whether I was in root or user while these process?

directory name includes the source file:GAMIT
path: /home/sorbilene/GAMIT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can put this at the end of your script?

```
read -p "$USER"
```